# How do I get Atom editor to show the terminal and the output when the script is run?

Tags: linux, python, atom-editor

I have added a script package which works fine.

After I run the Python script,  where do I see the output of the script? I have the screens divided and all I see is the following:

[image]

This is the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('http://meinparlament.diepresse.com/')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"content-question"})
for x in table:
    print x.find('p').text

# Another way to retrieve tables:
# table = soup.select('div[class="content-question"]')
```

How can I arrange Atom so that I can see

- the script
- the command-line
- the output of the Python script?

[image]